# Terraform provisioning new servers from the same template

Tags: terraform

Is there any trick to provision multiple aws stacks using previously created terraform template?

After applying some changes in variables file in order do not create the same resources but similar with new names.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain multiple "copies" of some infrastructure described in Terraform, the standard way to do that is to factor those common parts of the configuration into a shared [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html) and then call that module multiple times, either from inside the same configuration or across multiple separate configurations.

The Terraform ["state"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/) artifact tracks the relationships between objects in the configuration and objects in remote systems. Each configuration generally has only one state (unless you are using advanced features like [multiple workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)) and therefore one set of corresponding remote objects.

Using multiple configurations sharing the same module allows many instances to coexist as a result of being in separate state snapshots altogether.

Using several calls to the same module in a *single* configuration also allows many instances to coexist, this time by using the modules themselves as separate namespaces within the state snapshots.